# getting a flat record data structure out of a nested list in Clojure

Tags: clojure, record, tree-traversal

Let's say I have a list of lists representing a tree-structure in clojure, like

```clj
'(a (b (c d)) (e (f)))
```

and I want to translate it into a record format like this (for the purpose of passing it off to a visualization package):

```clj
[{:id "0" :label "a" :parent nil}
 {:id "1" :label "b" :parent "0"}
 {:id "2" :label "c" :parent "1"}
 {:id "3" :label "d" :parent "1"}
 {:id "4" :label "e" :parent "0"}
 {:id "5" :label "f" :parent "4"}]
```

What's the right way to go about this? 
I am pretty shaky with this, but I would think of starting with `defrecord`, and then some way of looping through the tree, but I don't know how to get started.

```clj
(def tree '(a (b (c d)) (e (f))))
(defn list-to-record [l]
  (defrecord rec [id name parent])
  (let [counter (atom 0)]
  (into [] (map ->rec 
                      ... ... ...))))

(list-to-record tree)
```

Perhaps I should be using `clojure.walk`?

---

Edit: to clarify, this should work regardless of what the labels are, so changing the labels in the input list shouldn't do anything to the resulting structure (the :parent values for each :id).  That is, the following list, just as above, but with the labels all the same as each other

```clj
'(a (a (a a)) (a (a)))
```

should get translated into

```clj
[{:id "0" :label "a" :parent nil}
 {:id "1" :label "a" :parent "0"}
 {:id "2" :label "a" :parent "1"}
 {:id "3" :label "a" :parent "1"}
 {:id "4" :label "a" :parent "0"}
 {:id "5" :label "a" :parent "4"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with Clojure zippers and `loop` + `recur`:

```
(defn index-zipper [z]
  (loop [loc z, next-id 0, parent-ids [], acc []]
    (cond
      (z/end? loc) acc

      (and (z/node loc) (not (z/branch? loc)))
      (recur
        (z/next loc)
        (inc next-id)
        (cond
          (some-> (z/right loc) z/branch?) (conj parent-ids next-id)
          (not (z/right loc)) (some-> parent-ids not-empty pop)
          :else parent-ids)
        (conj acc
              {:id     (str next-id)
               :label  (str (z/node loc))
               :parent (when (seq parent-ids)
                         (str (peek parent-ids)))}))

      :else
      (recur (z/next loc) next-id parent-ids acc))))
```

The `loop` has bindings for:

1. Current zipper `loc`ation
2. Next `:id` value, to be incremented each time we see a leaf node
3. Stack (vector) of current parent `:id`s, which will be pushed/popped as the zipper descends/ascends. The `:parent` value for each leaf node is on the top of the `parent-ids` stack.
4. `acc`umulator vector for leaf node maps

You can call the function with a zipper:

```
(index-zipper (z/seq-zip '(a (b (c d)) (e (f)))))
=>
[{:id "0", :label "a", :parent nil}
 {:id "1", :label "b", :parent "0"}
 {:id "2", :label "c", :parent "1"}
 {:id "3", :label "d", :parent "1"}
 {:id "4", :label "e", :parent "0"}
 {:id "5", :label "f", :parent "4"}]

(index-zipper (z/seq-zip '(a (a (a a)) (a (a)))))
=>
[{:id "0", :label "a", :parent nil}
 {:id "1", :label "a", :parent "0"}
 {:id "2", :label "a", :parent "1"}
 {:id "3", :label "a", :parent "1"}
 {:id "4", :label "a", :parent "0"}
 {:id "5", :label "a", :parent "4"}]
```

Comment: Actually, @taylor-wood, I discovered, this doesn't always work if there are multiple labels that are the same. For example, if you run your code on the list `'(a (a (a a)))` you get a depth one tree (all leaves connected directly to the root).  this is not good... I'm trying to figure it out now.

Comment: ah yes, thank you again. that's what I was trying to do, but you're better at this (also I'd never seen `peek` before. useful).

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way to do it.  You just have to add the part about assigning an "id" to each node.

Note also that you should re-format your input data so each node is in Hiccup format (i.e. even singleton nodes w/o children are wrapped in a vector).

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t]))

(def tree
  [:a
   [:b
    [:c]
    [:d]]
   [:e
    [:f]]])

(def relationships (atom []))

(defn save-relationships
  [parent-id curr-node]
  (let [curr-id   (first curr-node)
        kid-nodes (rest curr-node)]
    (swap! relationships #(conj % {:parent parent-id :label curr-id}))
    (doseq [kid-node kid-nodes]
      (save-relationships curr-id kid-node))))

(dotest
  (reset! relationships [])
  (save-relationships nil tree)
  (spyx-pretty @relationships))
```

with result:

```
~/expr/demo > 
~/expr/demo > lein test

lein test _bootstrap

-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 12
-------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.core
(clojure.core/deref relationships) => 
[{:parent nil, :label :a}
 {:parent :a, :label :b}
 {:parent :b, :label :c}
 {:parent :b, :label :d}
 {:parent :a, :label :e}
 {:parent :e, :label :f}]

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```